# How to make a webservice publicly accessible on the internet

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis-7, hosting

I finally finish my web services, I have test with local host and in my network now what I'd like to do is send my web service to be uploaded to the internet.

I wrote my web service in C#, asp.net using the nodepad (and not using visual studio), also I use IIS for the localhost, so the files i have in my virtual directory are:

1. Web-Based Service Consumer: WebApp.aspx
2. FirstService.asmx
3. FirstService.cs
4. FirstService.dll

Now in localhost works great, but I have no idea of how to publish on the internet. Can someone explain or send a guideline, let me remember that i am not using Visual Studio (and dont want to, don't ask why).

The only thing I know is that I have to have a server working with IIS. Is this true?

Comment: You can use FTP tools to upload all your files to server. You can ask your support team if you have any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes now you need to pay for an IIS hosting account to serve your files remotely for the world to see.

For example:
http://uk.godaddy.com/hosting/web-hosting.aspx

They will probably give you an FTP account where you can upload your files and some sort of web interface for you to configure the server. If you talk to them, I'm sure they can walk you through it.

Good luck.